# Convert CSV to Objects

Tags: javascript, csv, javascript-objects

**Considering the below string which contains countries and their capitals in csv format.**

```
let str = `
"country","capital"
"Afghanistan","Kabul"
"Argentina","Buenos Aires"
"Australia","Canberra"
"Austria","Vienna"
"Bangladesh","Dhaka"
"Barbados","Bridgetown"
"Bhutan","Thimphu"
"Brazil","Brasília"
"Canada","Ottawa"
"China","Beijing"
"Denmark","Copenhagen"
"Egypt","Cairo"
"Finland","Helsinki"
"France","Paris"
"Germany","Berlin"
"Greece","Athens"
"India","New Delhi"
"Indonesia","Jakarta"
"Iran","Tehran"
"Iraq","Baghdad"
"Ireland","Dublin"
"Israel","Jerusalem"
"Italy","Rome"
"Japan","Tokyo"

`
```

**How to write a function that takes this string as an input argument and returns an object where the keys are the countires and the values are the corresponding capitals.
output should look something like:**

```
{
  "Afghanistan": "Kabul",
  "Argentina": "Buenos Aires"
  etc...
}
```

Comment: What have you tried until now? Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: I haven't worked with CSV format until now so couldn't do much.

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with CSV per se. You have a string in a given format, which have to be parsed.

Comment: Nope the output must be as I have mentioned! @pilchard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another example using a traditional approach.

Note this one actually takes the header into account.

1. Split on each line
2. Remove the header
3. Split each line on the comma
4. Use array[0] as key and array[1] as value

```js
let str = `"country","capital"
"Afghanistan","Kabul"
"Argentina","Buenos Aires"
"Australia","Canberra"
"Austria","Vienna"
"Bangladesh","Dhaka"
"Barbados","Bridgetown"
"Bhutan","Thimphu"
"Brazil","Brasília"
"Canada","Ottawa"
"China","Beijing"
"Denmark","Copenhagen"
"Egypt","Cairo"
"Finland","Helsinki"
"France","Paris"
"Germany","Berlin"
"Greece","Athens"
"India","New Delhi"
"Indonesia","Jakarta"
"Iran","Tehran"
"Iraq","Baghdad"
"Ireland","Dublin"
"Israel","Jerusalem"
"Italy","Rome"
"Japan","Tokyo"`;

const out = {};
str.replace(/"/g,'')
       .split("\n") // each line
       .slice(1) // remove header
       .map(d=>{let a = d.split(','); out[a[0]] = a[1];}); //extract
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the many solutions:

```js
let countries = {};
str.match(/".+?"/g).forEach(function(word, index, words) {
    if ((index > 1) && (index % 2 === 0)) {
    countries[word] = words[index+1];
  }
});
console.log(countries);
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```js
let str = `
"country","capital"
"Afghanistan","Kabul"
"Argentina","Buenos Aires"
"Australia","Canberra"
"Austria","Vienna"
"Bangladesh","Dhaka"
"Barbados","Bridgetown"
"Bhutan","Thimphu"
"Brazil","Brasília"
"Canada","Ottawa"
"China","Beijing"
"Denmark","Copenhagen"
"Egypt","Cairo"
"Finland","Helsinki"
"France","Paris"
"Germany","Berlin"
"Greece","Athens"
"India","New Delhi"
"Indonesia","Jakarta"
"Iran","Tehran"
"Iraq","Baghdad"
"Ireland","Dublin"
"Israel","Jerusalem"
"Italy","Rome"
"Japan","Tokyo"

`;

let res = {}
str.split("\n")
.filter(item => item)
.forEach((item, index) => {
    if(index == 0) return;

    let line = item.split(",")
    res[line[0].slice(1,-1)] = line[1].slice(1,-1)
});

console.log(res);
```